# C# RunAs /Smartcard

Tags: c#, smartcard, remote-server

My application used to accept username/password to authenticate to a remote share (on Windows server) and then get the file listings etc.

```
public int ConnectNetResource(string server, string user, string password, ref string driveLeter) {
        NETRESOURCE net = new NETRESOURCE();
        net.dwScope = 0;
        net.dwType = 0;
        net.dwDisplayType = 0;
        net.dwUsage = 0;
        net.lpRemoteName = server;
        net.lpLocalName = driveLeter;
        net.lpProvider = null;

        return WNetAddConnection2(ref net, password, user, 0);

    }
```

Now, we need to authenticate using SmartCard. I have code to GetSmartCards, but I do not know how to make use of the certificate to authenticate.

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            // Nothing to do if no cert found.
            if (store.Certificates != null && store.Certificates.Count > 0)
            {
                if (store.Certificates.Count == 1)
                {
                    // Return the certificate present.
                    certificate = store.Certificates[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    // Request the user to select a certificate 
                    var certificates = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Digital Certificates", "Select a certificate from the following list:", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
                    // Check if one has been returned
                    if (certificates != null && certificates.Count > 0)
                        certificate = certificates[0];
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
        return certificate;

    }
```

GetClientCertificate function will return a user selected certificate, now HOW do I use this certificate to connect to a remote share. What API's or .dll can i use.

Btw, I am a windows engineer who can google code and make it work somehow. Will greatly appreciate a working code. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, RunAs.exe /smartcard commandline only makes uses of 1st smartcard, it cannot prompt user for a 2nd or 3rd smartcard and so the problem. Thank you.